# Next.js exportPathMap dynamic creations without defining each page in path

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

I want to define dynamic routes in next.js main issue is that i do not want to define each page in paths 
using react and next to build and export static files to deploy on S3 server

What is working

```
const exposedConfigs = {
  exportTrailingSlash: true,
  exportPathMap: async function() {
    const paths = {
      '/': { page: '/' },
      '/login': { page: '/login' },
      '/dashboard': { page: '/dashboard' },
      '/edit': { page: '/edit' },
      '/logout': { page: '/logout' },
      '/page1': { page: '/page1' },
      '/page2': { page: '/page2' },
      '/page3': { page: '/page3' }
    };
    return paths;
  }
};
const configuration = Object.assign(exposedConfigs);
module.exports = configuration;
```

above work well but i do not want to define them 
what above create in build is like

```
example:
login/index.html
dashboard/index.html 
etc
```

that is what i wanted but do not want to define each page path in routes because there are many pages and will increase with time

Solution i found but not working

```
const fetch = require('isomorphic-fetch');
const exposedConfigs = {
  exportTrailingSlash: true,
  exportPathMap: async function () {
    //provide default path here.
    const paths = {
    };
    const res = await fetch(fetchRoutes.getUrl());
    const data = await res.json();
    const mappedUrls = fetchRoutes.processData(data);
    mappedUrls.forEach(url => {
      paths[url] = { page: url };
    });
    return paths;
  }
};
const configuration = Object.assign(exposedConfigs);
module.exports = configuration;
```

it gives fetchRoutes undefined error .any help will be great